How to improve cython code to make it faster than numpy select function?
I am trying to make a code faster than "numpy select" but it is slower than numpy.
numpy select is twice faster than my cython code.
I tried big dataset and small dataset but both of cases numpy select is faster (numpy select 11.4ms, cython code 24ms)
%timeit compute_np(300)
# 11.4 ms ± 1.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit compute_cy(300)
# 24.8 ms ± 1.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

I tried methods in the cython documents but failed to reduce speed gap.
Here is my detailed cython code.
Used packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cython
import random
import timeit
import time
%load_ext Cython

Used dataset
dur_m = np.random.randint(1, 1001, size=100000)
pol_year = np.random.randint(1, 1001, size=100000)
calc_flag = 1
type = np.random.choice(['IF','NB', 'NB2', 'NB3'], size = 100000)

rand = np.arange(0.01, 0.05, 0.0001)
output1 = np.random.choice(rand, size=100000)
output2 = np.random.choice(rand, size=100000)
output3 = np.random.choice(rand, size=100000)

Numpy test
def compute_np(t):
    
    condition = [
    (t > dur_m) & (t < pol_year) & (calc_flag ==1),
    (t < dur_m) & (calc_flag ==1),
    (t < pol_year)
    ]
        
    result = [
    output1,
    output2,
    output3
    ]

    default = np.array([0] * 100000)

    return np.select(condition, result, default)

Cython code
%%cython --annotate
import cython
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def select_cy2(np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, ndim = 2, cast=True] conditions, double [:, ::1] choice, double [:] default_value):
    cdef int num_condition = conditions.shape[0]
    cdef int length = conditions.shape[1]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] result = np.zeros(length, dtype=np.float64)
    cdef int i, j
    for j in range(length):
        for i in range(num_condition):
            if conditions[i,j]:
                result[j] = choice[i,j]
                break
            else:
                result[j] = default_value[i]
    return result

Cython test
def compute_cy(t):
    
    condition = [
    (t > dur_m) & (t < pol_year) & (np.array([calc_flag]*100000) ==1), 
    (t < dur_m) & (np.array([calc_flag]*100000) ==1), 
    (t < pol_year)]
        
    result = [
    output1, 
    output2, 
    output3]

    default = np.array([0.0] * 100000)

    return select_cy(np.array(condition), np.array(result), default)

Is there anyone who can suggest the method to improve the speed?

Could you complete your question with the timeit.timeit(...) call that gives your measures?

I did put it :)

I haven't timed this so it could be wrong, but you're repeatedly copying default_value. Maybe:
    for j in range(length):
        result[j] = default_value[num_condition-1]
        for i in range(num_condition):
            if conditions[i,j]:
                result[j] = choice[i,j]
                break

or
    for j in range(length):
        for i in range(num_condition):
            if conditions[i,j]:
                result[j] = choice[i,j]
                break
        else:
            result[j] = default_value[num_condition-1]

You can also allocate the result using np.empty rather than np.zeros since you overwrite every element of it.
Typically the Numpy internals are pretty well-written (in either C, Fortran or Cython) so there aren't big wins to be had by rewriting individual Numpy functions. If you can eliminate a series of Numpy functions (so avoid allocating a number of intermediate arrays) then it starts to be worthwhile.

Actually default value should be located inside of "for loop". It is to calculate if condition[i, j] is fault.. thanks for your answer anyway :)

I didn't get it quite right (I've made a small edit) but there really isn't a need to do that work for every i

I applied your recommendation and it is very close to numpy select. Thanks a lot !!
numpy select:
11.3 ms ± 957 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
cython:
11.6 ms ± 934 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

The actual problem is your setup function. If you cut down the test functions:
def compute_np(t):
    
    condition = [
    (t > dur_m) & (t < pol_year) & (calc_flag ==1),
    (t < dur_m) & (calc_flag ==1),
    (t < pol_year)
    ]
        
    result = [
    output1,
    output2,
    output3
    ]

    default = np.array([0] * 100000)

def compute_cy(t):
    
    condition = [
    (t > dur_m) & (t < pol_year) & (np.array([calc_flag]*100000) ==1), 
    (t < dur_m) & (np.array([calc_flag]*100000) ==1), 
    (t < pol_year)]
        
    result = [
    output1, 
    output2, 
    output3]

    default = np.array([0.0] * 100000)

(i.e. remove the Numpy or Cython calls) then time it
>>> timeit("compute_np(300)", globals=globals(), number=100)
0.5298301999864634
>>> timeit("compute_cy(300)", globals=globals(), number=100)
1.4147169000061695

the difference is almost all in what you do to initialize the inputs. The work of select is pretty much irrelevant.
I believe my suggestions in my other answer make a small difference, but the main issue is that you're not measuring what you think.

That's very interesting.. I have to investigate further. Thanks for your comment!!
